# Associate Pattern Element with More than One Node in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
match (rootTk:Toolkit {level: "Level 0"})<-[:PrimaryChild*]-(tk:Toolkit)<-[:visitTo]-(hit:PageHit)
return rootTk.title, count(hit.id)
```

In this scenario, each rootTk represents the root of a tree of toolkits. I’d like to return the number of hits related to each tree. The above query is close to what I want, but it does not include the hits related to the root of each tree, only its children.

How would I associate the `<-[:visitTo]-(hit:PageHit)` part of the pattern with both the child toolkits and the associated root toolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT - Jim's answer**
Jim has a better answer for this question which anyone finding this question should use.

```
MATCH (rootTk:Toolkit {level: "Level 0"})<-[:PrimaryChild*0..]-(tk:Toolkit)<-[:visitTo]-(hit:PageHit)
RETURN rootTk.title as Title,COUNT(hit.id) as Hits
```

It uses a 0 length (to infinity) path match to make the PrimaryChild relationship non-mandatory.

**Original Answer**

```
MATCH (rootTk:Toolkit {level: "Level 0"})<-[:PrimaryChild*]-(tk:Toolkit)<-[:visitTo]-(hit:PageHit)
RETURN rootTk.title, COUNT(hit)
```

As you said this will return the hits on the tk nodes only, to get hits on the root I think that this will work:

```
MATCH (rootTk:Toolkit {level: "Level 0"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (rootTk)<-[:PrimaryChild*]-(tk:Toolkit)<-[:visitTo]-(hit:PageHit)
WITH rootTk, COUNT(hit) as hits
OPTIONAL MATCH (rootTk)<-[:visitTo]-(rootHit:PageHit)
RETURN rootTk.title, hits + COUNT(rootHit)
```

It performs the count in two phases and adds the values, I'm not sure that there is a way to do it in a single phase without amending your model.

I guess you could do this, but you might explode:

```
MATCH (rootTk:Toolkit {level: "Level 0"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (rootTk)<-[*]-(hit:PageHit)
RETURN rootTk.title, COUNT(hit)
```

Answer (score 1):

While optional matches can solve the problem, a simpler solution is to use zero as the starting point in the path lenght range. This includes the root item in the tree.

MATCH (rootTk:Toolkit {level: "Level 0"})<-[:PrimaryChild*0..]-(tk:Toolkit)<-[:visitTo]-(hit:PageHit)
RETURN rootTk.title as Title,COUNT(hit.id) as Hits

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know you could match zero length paths like that, this is the correct answer.